# (1) Create a job flow, (2) copy-paste program sheets and (3) action of specific a specific program (sheet) - sas

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I am quite new to SAS, and I am having a general question that I am interested in:

This question englobes 3 small questions:

Those are:

1. How to create a job flow using SAS Code
2. How to copy paste programs sheets (from a main file) and changing their name for another using SAS Code.
3. How to run these programs just created using SAS Code.
   Besides the potential question to the purpose of it, I am gonna ilustrate what I have and what I want:

Is it possible to do so ?

I have not been able to supply my SAS file example for it, but it would only have something written the Main program, which is:

> ```
>   %let products = A B;
>   %let years = 2014 2015;
>   for year in years:
>        for type in products:    
>             (1) create flux with name product{i}years{year}
>             (2) copypaste the programs Code1, Code2 with name as shown in example 
>             (3) run Code1-YYYYP, Code2-YYYYP
> ```

[image]

I don't either want someone to make me the loops, since I can do that. I only want to know the code for inside the loop.

Thank you in advanced for your time and consideration,

Comment: Sounds like you are asking for help with using Enterprise Guide and not the SAS language itself.  Or are you just using those pictures to explain a logical concept that want to actually implement in SAS code?

Comment: Yes, the second one. I just want to know the code for making the actions of copy-paste sheets, renaming a sheet, creating a process flow and creating an empty sheet: What you would do with clicks but with code.

Comment: The SAS language itself has no concept of copy/paste sheets.  What product are those pictures you pasted in taken of?  Are you asking for a programming interface to Enterprise Guide?

Comment: You can create a macro to encapsulate a series of steps.  Then you can call the macro wherever you need it. You can even define the macro to take parameters.  You can also just use `%include` to pull in code from text files.  Is that what you want to do?  It would help if you constructed a concrete example of what you want to do.

Comment: I’m just asking for the SAS code of the actions i can do with clicks, or a page I can find this commands. That s all. I am sorry but I do not understand what is not clear from my question.

Comment: Again click inside of WHAT?  The screen shots do NOT look like they came from SAS Display Manager. So they are not something you can program with SAS.  If you are using Enterprise Guide or one of the many other SAS applications/products you need to say which one you are using.

Comment: I’m using Sas Entreprise guide, if that is your question

Comment: Click means when one does click on new: and then you choose between different options: flow or a program or whatever one can choose ( i Don’t have right now sas in front of me so i cannot make a screenshot until tomorrow for you to see it exactly. Maybe that way of showing what to create new is unique in Sas Entreprise guide). I’m sorry I Don’t know how to be More precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use SAS code to control Enterprise Guide.  Enterprise GUI is Windows application that can connect to a SAS server and allow you to create and run SAS programs. But the puppet cannot control the puppeteer.

You could try seeing if a custom TASK in Enterprise Guide could do something like what you want.  https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/guide/customtasks/book/

Comment: Sad to hear that :(